# SQL Ce 4 - How can I run DBCC CHECKIDENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I want to run DBCC CHECKIDENT on a SqlCe4 database but it wont let me.

I need to reset the identity column as its messed up. I think because IDENTITY was turned off, an import of data was done and then IDENTITY turned on again so I guess its out of sync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no DBCC CHECKIDENT in SQL CE 4.

You need to use ALTER TABLE.

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [IdentityColumn] IDENTITY (999,1).

Comment: Our organization has used this same command to support reseeding SQL Compact databases. Unfortunately, it will sometimes cause primary key constraint violations. In one case we had to DROP/CREATE instead.